# Why does my ready function always run when controller or directive reinisilize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

When my controller or directive reinisilize `angular.element(document).ready(function(){...});` function always runs. Why?

I have two controllers and one directive. I change value from parent controller which assign to `ng-repeat`. Whenever I change this variable, controller reinsilize and ready function recall too.

See this link: [angualr ready function](https://plnkr.co/edit/YxtfdyH5PJ46dPVLnD3w?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is set up such that you are destroying and recreating things when you click the "change index" button:

```
that.changeIndex = function(){
    that.arr = [{name : g++}];
    that.isValid = !that.isValid;
}
```

`ng-repeat` destroys and recreates your `myCon2` controllers when you create a new `arr` array:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in con.arr track by m.name" ng-controller="myCon2 as con1">
```

And `ng-if` destroys or recreates your `my-dir` directive when you change `isValid`:

```
<div my-dir ng-if="con.isValid">hey directive!!!!</div>
```

The controller and directive both attach a handler to document ready, which will run as long as the document is ready (not just as soon as it becomes ready). This makes sense because if your code loads after the document initially becomes ready, you'd usually still want it to run.

By the way, you shouldn't need to use document ready inside Angular controllers and directives. You can put your initialization code at the top of them, or you can use `ng-init`.